# how to pass array Data one-Page to other page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, multidimensional-array

I Get data form like this

```
 $('input:checked').each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
          var itemName= $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').text();
        var itemCost=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(3)').text();   // admin
       var itemQty= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4) input').val(); 
 });
```

I have 4 textFields like this
[image]
When I Click on Check-box.We Need to Pass Data(name,cost,Qty) to Next-Page.if We Click 4 check-box .We need 4 name and 4 cost and 4 qty value pass to next-Page.

Please any one guide.Please tell me Total Data will pass to other page.We redirect page like this

```
window.location = '../html/NextPage.html';
```

Comment: most people would post data to server and do redirect there

Comment: @charlietfl in this case i don't have server if any other chances

Comment: Can use cookie or localStorage. Otherwise there is no state saving between page loads in browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the below:

Here's a working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4qk82d10/4/)

```
var myStuffArray =[];
$('input:checked').each(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        var itemName= $(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(1)').text();
        var itemCost=$(this).closest('tr').children('td:eq(2)').text();   
        var itemQty= $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(3) input').val(); 
       myStuffArray.push([itemName, itemCost, itemQty]);    
 });

//store in local storage
localStorage["myStuffLocalArray"] = JSON.stringify(myStuffArray);

//... on second page
var myRetrievedStuffArray = JSON.parse(localStorage["myStuffLocalArray"]);
alert (myRetrievedStuffArray[0][0]); //alerts the first "itemName"
```

Comment: @DDelightedD0D thanks so muct Please some help i tried to get itemNames like this alert(myRetrievedStuffArray[i].itemName); but it's showing undefined

Comment: please tell how to get itemNames and itemCost and itemQty We Tried like this alert(myRetrievedStuffArray[i].itemName); but no luck please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can use localStorage/sessionStorage for saving the data.

```
Try to save the data in json object of possible.
```